# Editing multiple similar shapes in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

My question is actually two-fold. I'm rather new to draw.io but I'm coming across two difficulties.

1. Let's suppose that I have used a shape to illustrate similar things (let's say that I have used six Database shapes, all with the same size). If later on I want to modify their size, I can't see another way than changing them all one by one.
   Is there another way? I have in mind Microsoft Powerpoint in which I can select multiple shapes and right click (or use the top menu) to change their sizes.
2. Again, if I have used a shape to illustrate similar things (let's say that I have used six Actor1 shapes) but later on I want to change those identical shapes to another (from Actor1 tor Actor2). One way I see to do it is to change them one by one. I do suppose it's not possible to do otherwise at the moment, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try File, Edit and replace shape=xy with shape=zx using a text editor.

Comment: Indeed, that does the trick for both my problems. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sadly this is not available any more!

Answer (score 5):

You can also:

1. Box select a number of shapes,
2. Drag a new shape type over one of the shapes in the selection,
3. When you see the replace shape icon, release the mouse,
4. All selected entities will be changed to the new shape type.

Answer (score 2):

For those who might come here searching for an up-to-date answer: you can simply group the objects that you want to simultaneously resize (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).
That way you're able to resize the group as you would any single item.